# Sending data from a file on iPad to a php file on server via AJAX

Tags: ajax, ipad, url, send

I'm trying to upload data captured in a local html file on an iPad and save it to server.

I found this: [Sending data to an external file via Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597596/sending-data-to-an-external-file-via-ajax)

So as far as I can understand, there is no way to send the info doing something like this:
    ajax.open("POST",'http://www.misite.com/canvas/testSave.php',true);
from a html on the iPad, I'm right?

So I just want to know if anyone knows a trick to do this. Thanks!

Comment: Based on your own answer below - how is this specific to iPad? You'd probably get more responses if your question was more generic.

Comment: I understand what you say. I asked my question in this way because some of the solutions I founded in my search worked with other browsers but did not with safari for iOS. I fact part of the code used for the canvas (not posted here) it's not working with Chrome and IE. That's the reason my friend. But as you say this can work in other platforms and browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a couple of weeks this is what I could achieved.

1.- The function that sends the data (an image generated from a canvas):

```
function sendImageData()
    {
        var filename = $("#filename").val().trim();
   if(filename == ''){
    alert("File name is needed");
    return;
   }

        var uploadCanvas = $("#uploadCanvas");
        var canvasData = uploadCanvas[0].toDataURL("image/png");
        var debugConsole= $("#debugConsole");
        debugConsole.val(canvasData);

      $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "http://yourremoteserver.com/canvas/save.php",
            data: {
        canvasData:canvasData,
        filename:filename
    }
        }).done(function() {
                    alert("saved: " + filename + ".png");// THIS IS NOT WORKING YET.
                }
                );
    }
```

2.- The PHP that receives and saves the data:

```
<?php
$imagen = $_POST['canvasData'];
$filename = $_POST['filename'];

if (isset($imagen)){
    $imageData=$imagen;
    $filteredData=substr($imageData, strpos($imageData, ",")+1);
    $unencodedData=base64_decode($filteredData);
    $fp = fopen( $filename.'.png', 'wb' );
    fwrite( $fp, $unencodedData);
    fclose( $fp );
}
?>
```

If anyone can help me with the `.done` function to work (remember, the html file is in an ipad and the php on a server) let me know. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) for this purpose. It automagically switches between flash, silverlight, and html5 so it should work on just about any browser (including the safari on the iPad). Basically, it uploads a file to a processing script with some generated id (it generates it for you). Then, you can poll another page to get the uploaded data once it is finished uploading.

EDIT: Re-reading your post I am not sure how pertinent this is since it requires the user to select a file and I'm not sure that's what you are getting at exactly.

Comment: Hi, I want to upload an image generated from a canvas via toDataURL. Maybe this can do it, will check it and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: Didn't work but I think I'm finding a solution. I will post it when it's done.